# WSO2 API Manager: Configuration of the access-files consumed services

Tags: api, logging, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Where can I configure the log file of the services that are consumed by the consumers? I noticed that by default the file is created in:

```
$WSO2_AM_HOME/repository/logs/http_access_<date>.log
```

I have changed in the $WSO2_AM_HOME/repository/conf/log4j.properties to point all the logfiles to /data/logs, but I see still this http_access_ logile created every day. Where can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http_access logs files are prefixed with “http_access_”. These files include access information for the server. We can get the access information for webapps also from this. These logs rotates on daily basis.

In Carbon 4.0.* based products, you can disable http access logs by removing the following entry from catalina-server.xml which is located in $CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat.

For the products which uses nhttp transport (Ex. WSO2 ESB) you also have to define the below entry in log4j.properties file. 
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.Access=WARN
log4j.properties file is located in $CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/